# Passing the pointer to the first element of a vector if any

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I have a function taking double*

```
void funct(double*);
```

and I have a vector:

```
std::vector<double> myVec;
```

how should I correctly and safely call funct(myVec)?

not safe:

```
funct(&myVec[0]);
funct(&*myVec.begin());
```

not nice to be read:

```
funct( myVec.empty()? NULL : &myVec[0]);
funct( myVec.empty()? NULL : &*myVec.begin());
```

any suggestion?

What's the standard approach?

Comment: vOv I may as well say it, why can't you rewrite the function to take a sensible type?

Comment: What do you want to do inside `funct`?

Comment: @Jeffrey funct() is legacy code, it knows runtime somehow how long the double* is. So if myVec.size is zero the pointer is not used. 
But I was wondering what meaningfull option I have to deal with the need to provide a pointer to the content of a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the standard class type `std::vector` has a member function called `data`, that is supposed to return *the pointer to the underlying storage*. [Apparently](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) `data()` is nothing more than `&front()` with the guaranteed that:

> The pointer is such that range `[data(); data() + size())` is always a valid range, even if the container is empty.

Therefore I'd say that both:

```
funct(vector.data());
funct(&vector.front());
```

can be safely used.

But the real question is: what are you trying to do inside the function?

I can see 3 obvious answers to this, and I'm going to propose alternatives for all:

1. I only want one element of the array
2. I want an optional argument
3. I want to pass a container

---

Let's start with the first, shall we? If you only want an element of the array, why bother with pointers and array in general? You can just use:

```
void funct(double);
```

and be done with it. And if you want to modify that `double`, why not pass it by reference?

```
void funct(double&);
```

and call the function as:

```
funct(vector[0]);
```

---

The number two has two very possible answers. One is to use function overloading like this:

```
void funct();
void funct(double);
```

And basically consider the function with no argument and an argument. The simplest solution is probably the right one, correct?

Otherwise, if you are really feeling fancy and you can't be bothered to write `funct` two times, you can even use `boost::optional` or [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++14), which clearly express the intent of the argument:

```
void funct(std::optional<double> optional) {
    if (optional) {
        // we have a double
    } else {
        // we don't have a double
    }
}
```

---

And finally, the third one has three possible answers (can you see the pattern?).

If you only want a specific kind of container (why would you want that, only God knows) you can simply do:

```
void funct(const std::vector<double>&);
```

Otherwise you can either use templates like [Bartek explained **below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556536/493122) or use my favorite solution: *iterators* (which is the choice of standard algorithms as well, just to make it less official).

And guess what? It works also with C-style arrays (which you shouldn't be using by the way). Here's the solution:

```
template<class Iterator>
void funct(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        // do something to element (*it)
    }
}
```

And BOOM. You can use it like this:

```
double x[100];
funct(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
```

or:

```
std::vector<double> x(100);
funct(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Happy coding.

Comment: funct(std::begin(x), std::end(x));

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has member function `data`. So you can use it like this:

```
func(nyVec.data());
```

I did not find in the Standard that if a vector is empty then `data` has to return `0`. Maybe it is a Standard defect. Though an empty vector can has non-zero capacity.

If you need to check whether a `vector` is empty then you can write:

```
func(myVec.empty() ? NULL : nyVec.data());
```

Usually if you pass an array by value you should specify a second parameter that will contain the size of the array. So maybe it would be better if `func` was declared as:

```
func(double *, std::vector<double>::size_type);
```

In this case you could call the function as:

```
func(myVec.data(), myVec.size());
```

If you need to process only one element then the standard approach is the following:

```
if (!myVec.empty()) func(&myVec.front());
```

Comment: `.data` doesn't guarantee to return a null pointer for empty vectors, though.

Comment: how is this more safe than OP's funct( myVec.empty()? NULL : &myVec[0]);

Comment: @ piotruś It is the exact same thing. There is no better way.

Comment: @piotruś I think using data instead of construction as &myVec[0] makes code more readable and compatible with other containers.

Comment: OP just wants to pass the first element, not the array, so size is useless.

Comment: `(double *, size_type)` is **NOT** passing an array by value. `void(double[5])` is a function type that takes a `double` array by value. In your example it's a pointer and an integral size parameter.

Comment: @ Bartek Banachewicz This function declaration void(double[5]) is equivalent to void( double * ); They declare the same function.

Comment: A little pedantic, I know, but maybe you should consider `std::size_t` as a second function argument for the size if you want to use that function for something other than a `vector`.

Comment: And you may want to consider using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` (I think we can safely assume that in 2014, unless specified otherwise, OP uses C++11). Also because your answer suggests `data` which is only available on C++11 anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: If you're going to troll, at least troll with _facts_.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
funct(&myVec.at(0));
```

This performs bounds checking and will throw `std::out_of_range` if element is not within the range of the container.

Comment: That should be `&myVec.at(0)`.

Comment: @Snps I like the pun. Nice try!

Answer (score 1):

[std::vector `data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function returns a pointer to its internal data (array), so we can use it this way:

```
if ( !(myVec.size() == 0)) func( myVec.data());
```

or:

```
if ( !myVec.empty()) func( myVec.data());
```

The choose of `size()` or `empty()` is dependent on implementation of these functions that you are using. C++ standard guarantees that `empty()` is constant time for all standard containers.

Comment: Now, maybe you'll answer here; why is `size() == 0` preferred over `empty`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz is this your own blog that you write down your internal thoughts everywhere? I replied to your question in place where it should be replied

Comment: @piotrus as far as I know size() is not faster than empty() for every container in any meaningful implementation. 
Thanks for your answer. I didn't know of std::vector::data().

Answer (score 1):

Create a utility function. This will both hide the not-niceness and prevent code duplication.

```
template <class T>
typename T::value_type* first_ptr(T &&container)
{
  return container.empty() ? nullptr : &container.front();
}


int main()
{
  funct(first_ptr(myVec));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap or change the function into more idiomatic optional primitive:

```
void funct(optional<double&> f);
```

Let's think about the passing then. The function should, if the vector is not empty, pass the first element, and nothing otherwise.

Directly transcribes to

```
if (!v.empty()) {
    funct(v.front());
} else {
    funct(none);
}
```

I would probably change it to regular value semantics, though; referencing elements from collections directly is rather dangerous.

Of course you can pack it into a reusable function:

```
template<class Container>
optional<typename Container::value_type&> myFront(Container& cont) {
    if (!cont.empty())
        return cont.front();
    else
        return none;
}

funct(myFront(v));
```

Now you only need `lift` `:)`.

Comment: @piotruś **Why** is it better to use `size() == 0`? Also the name of the variable is really a placeholder, so I don't think it matters much.

Comment: @piotruś actually using `v.size()` is not guaranteed to be a constant operation (though all implementations do it in O(1). `empty()` is the way to go, plus it's more readable.

Comment: the standard does gurantee that empty() is a constant-time operation for all standard containers, size() is not necessary constant time, but in fact on many implementations size() for vector is preferred because empty is implemented using size()

Comment: The conventional wisdom (and the logical conclusion from the standard) is to use `empty()`, not `size() == 0`. Do you have a reputable source to back up the claim that the opposite is preferred? If not, then don't say it, otherwise others will learn incorrectly.

Comment: @piotruś: `size()` is guaranteed constant time for all standard containers, since C++11. And even before that, I believe only `std::list` was allowed some leeway because of splicing.

Comment: @concept3d: See my above comment.

Comment: @Xeo: Good call, I didn't know that had changed with C++11. Thanks!

Comment: @piotruś that argumentation doesn't make any sense, really. So you'd rather bet on the fact that `size()` is O(1) rather than use `empty` which is *guaranteed* to be O(1)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz no, I would check

Comment: @piotruś And write code that's dependent on a particular stdlib for *potential* speed gain that could be obtained by the fact that compiler can't inline the insides of `empty()`?

Comment: @Xeo good to know everything about C++ is going for the better. I should read more the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but anyway: this seems like an XY problem.

I would say none of the solutions proposed in the OP are good fits based on the following: it makes little sense to be calling a function with a null pointer argument so I would say this should be handled at the call site. Something like:

```
if(!myVec.empty()) funct(&myVec[0]);
else ...
```